# Internal Testing of Wear OS android app app link not functioning

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I uploaded a wear os app to play console and created internal testing track. After adding myself as a tester and accpeting the test invitation via the link provided, I attempted to download the app from play store onto the watch. The phone says an error has occured, try again.

[Phone Rejecting Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Bsw.png)

What would cause this issue, I am new to releasing apps to the play store so any advice is appreciated :)

I have tried using the link provided to download the app from the play store but it keeps returning an error. I was expecting to download the app to ensure it is fit for release.